# EXC_BAD_ACCESS-message in a while-loop

Tags: objective-c, xcode5

am new to objective-c and new to xcode
    In the following code, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=exc_1386_gpflt) at line marked B
    If I comment out lines marked a, then the remaining code works as intended.
    If I comment out lines marked c, then the remaining code works as intended.
    What am I missing?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main()
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
      NSMutableArray *queue = 
        [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];         // c
      NSMutableString *item = 
        [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:20]; // c
      [item setString:@"WHBs default string"];         // c
      char select[1] = "x", entry[20];
      NSLog(@"=>1: %@", item);                         // c
      while (select[0] != '0')                   // a
       {
        NSLog(@"select [1-5, 0 for exit]:");
        scanf("%1s", select);                    // a
        if (select[0] > '0' && select[0] <= '9') // a
         {
          NSLog(@"ENQ: enter the item");
          scanf ("%s", entry);
          NSLog(@"=>2: %s", entry);
          [item setString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:entry]]; // B, c
          NSLog(@"=>3: %@", item);  // c
          [queue addObject: item];  // c
          [queue addObject: item];  // c
          NSLog(@"=>4 contents of queue: %@", queue); // c
         }
        }
      NSLog(@"===> EXIT <===");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this here

```
char select[1] = "x"
```

is not correct, it is the same as

```
char select[1] = { 'x', '\0' };
```

you need two chars

```
char select[2] = "x"
```

one for the ending \0

Comment: Thank you! How simple it can be. But as I mentioned, I need much more experience.